# Css alternative to js solution, html in wrong order to use float

Tags: html, css

My framework is spitting out html in the wrong order for my layout. I could change it but for other media the order is correct. Currently I have a simple line of javascript to transport the html but I was wondering if there was a css alterative.

Here is the simplefied exaple. The first example is how it should work, the second is what I have now. I'd like to know if the same layout can be accomplished on the second example, the desired version wihtout using the javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/SPgyA/1/

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="right" class="somediv">
        div right, dont know height in advance
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        main text, dont know height in advance<br />   
        main text, dont know height in advance<br />   
        main text, dont know height in advance<br />   
    </div>
</div>


<div id="desired_wrap">
      <div id="desired_main">
        main text, dont know height in advance<br />   
        main text, dont know height in advance<br />   
        main text, dont know height in advance<br />   
    </div>
    <div id="desired_right" class="somediv">
        div right, dont know height in advance
    </div>
</div>
```

​

the javascript:

```
$("#desired_right").prependTo("#desired_wrap");
```

the css

```
#wrap,#desired_wrap{
    width:200px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px dashed grey;
}
#right{
    float:right;
}

#desired_right{
    float:right;
}


.somediv{
    color:red;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

​

Comment: What framework are you using? Also your question is very vague how can anyone answer if there is a css alternative if we don't know what your doing with javascript.

Comment: I'm sorry the javascript was in the fiddle. Seemed the best wawy to show it. As im unsure what the awnser would be so im not able to formulate the question verry well :-)

Comment: Im using a friends framework. It's really fast but isn't built for whay I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the way to handle this *with only CSS and without changing your HTML order*, by adding a small additional html attribute*:

**In my opinion, this is only possible way to get this work, because the floating behavior, specified by the w3c, can't work this way without adding at least one html attribute.*

### HTML

```
<div id="desired_wrap">
    <div id="desired_main" data-placeholder="my box text">
        main text, dont know height in advance<br />   
        main text, dont know height in advance<br />   
        main text, dont know height in advance<br />   
    </div>
    <div id="desired_right" class="somediv">
        my box text
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, we're placing the text from `data-placeholder` via the [`:before`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-before), before `#desired_main` via the [`content`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/content) css property.

This way, the height of the generated element will be exactly the same as the height from `#desired_right`, because they contain the same text.

### CSS

```
#desired_wrap{
    width:200px;
    padding:10px;
    position: relative;
}

.somediv {
    width: 100px;
}

#desired_main:before {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
}​
```

Positioning `#desired_right` absolute to the right top, will simulate a float right, like in your first, working example:

### CSS

```
#desired_right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

#### Works well in:

- Internet Explorer 8+
- Firefox 3.6
- Chrome 17+
- Safari 5+

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/SPgyA/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align the inner .somediv to the top right you need to add position:relative and absolute

```
#wrap,#desired_wrap{
    position:relative;
}

.somediv{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

EDIT:

Just realised that with that change the text no longer flows around the div...